# how to disable automatic URL encoding in flash

Tags: actionscript-2

i need to disable automatic url encoding in flash as2
because i have URL link with special characters š,č,á,é,í

need to disable all of '%' this

any help_?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In as2 this is not a problem as far as I know. But you can try

> System.useCodepage = true;